# Custom parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-effects, parallax

I'm trying to create my own custom parallax plugin so that I am able to choose the direction the items transition off the screen and I'm just stuck at making sure that no matter how a user scrolls and no matter of the size of the window that the object disappears at the correct point.

Currently I have:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var logoStartPos = $('.bg-logo').position().left;
$(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){

       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
          if($('.bg-logo').is(':in-viewport'))
            $('.bg-logo').css({'left':($('.bg-logo').position().left+10) + "px"});
       } else {
          if($('.bg-logo').is(':in-viewport') && logoStartPos < $('.bg-logo').position().left)
            $('.bg-logo').css({'left':($('.bg-logo').position().left-10) + "px"});
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;

   }); 
});
```

As you can guess this only moves the item right until it goes off screen. This way has varied results because if I use the scroll wheel it take longer to disappear to if I use the scroll bar. I also have another problem in that if I use a mixture or have a different view port I get an different result all together.

Any tips or pointers to achieve the result I'm after?

An working example of my code is at http://motoring.egl.me.uk

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit dated, but FYI...

In your jQuery initialize or ready event, you need to initialize each section, article, item or whatever it is (item.each) to instantiate a scroll function, so that each one has it's own scroll function.

```
this.each(function(index) {
```

Then in scroll function, only handle the event, if it is the 'current' section.  You will need some way to determine which item is the 'current' one.  Often this is done by saving each item's window size into a global array, and then using that compare to the current location.

Something like: (The way you designed your code will likely be very different)

```
// If this section is in view
if ( ($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) > (topOffset) &&
   ( (topOffset + $self.height()) > $window.scrollTop() ) )
```

In this way, once one item goes off the screen, the next item should become 'current' and continue the scrolling.